# How do I use InitiateAuth command (@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider) to trigger SRP Authentication followed by CUSTOM_CHALLANGE?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk, custom-authentication, srp-protocol

Desired Flow:

1. Begin with Cognito SRP flow to verify user's username and password combination
2. If Username and password are correct, then move to CUSTOM_CHALLENGE
3. Upon completion of CUSTOM_CHALLENGE (OTP verification), then issue token

When logging in using Cognito with MFA, I want the OTP generated by Cognito to be of the format `ABC-123456`. However after investigation I believe that this configuration is not available out of the box. i.e. Cognito seems to only generate OTPs of format `123456` (6-digits)

Therefore I utilised the `createAuth`, `defineAuth` and `verifyAuth` lambda triggers to handle the OTP generation and verification

However, I still need Cognito to handle username and password verification before handing things off to my lambda triggers.

I read that Cognito allows SRP Authentication (not plaintext username and password) followed by CUSTOM_CHALLENGE

I'm using @aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider library, but cannot seem to get the initiateAuth method to behave correctly. It skips the SRP Authentication and moves straight to my custom challanges.

Looking at the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/interfaces/initiateauthcommandinput.html)

> For CUSTOM_AUTH: USERNAME (required), SECRET_HASH (if app client is configured with client secret), DEVICE_KEY. To start the authentication flow with password verification, include ChallengeName: SRP_A and SRP_A: (The SRP_A Value).

Note: I'm not adding code snippets here as I will be answering below

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts that need to be tackled

1. Handling SRP authentication
2. Creating lambda triggers

**Handling SRP Authentication**

SRP authentication flow goes as such (NOTE this is to begin with SRP and **then** move to CUSTOM_CHALLENGE)

1. Generate `SRP_A`

```
  //npm install amazon-user-pool-srp-client
  import { SRPClient, calculateSignature, getNowString }from 'amazon-user-pool-srp-client';

  const userPoolId = this.userPoolId.split('_')[1]; //User pool id in env is in format of ap-southeast-1_9xxxxxx
  const srp = new SRPClient(userPoolId);
  const srpA = srp.calculateA();
```

2. InitateAuth Command with relevant parameters

```
   const initiateAuthParams = {
      AuthFlow: AuthFlowType.CUSTOM_AUTH,
      ClientId: this.clientId,
      AuthParameters: {
        USERNAME: phoneNumber, // My cognito is configured to allow phone number as an alias for username
        CHALLENGE_NAME: 'SRP_A',
        SRP_A: srpA,
      },
    };
    const command = new InitiateAuthCommand(initiateAuthParams);
    const initiateAuthResponse = await this.provider.send(command);
```

3. Response contains: `SALT`, `SECRET_BLOCK`, `SRP_B`, `USER_ID_FOR_SRP`, and `Session` (and more)

```
const userIdForSrp = initiateAuthResponse.ChallengeParameters.USER_ID_FOR_SRP;
const srpB = initiateAuthResponse.ChallengeParameters.SRP_B;
const salt = initiateAuthResponse.ChallengeParameters.SALT;
const secretBlock = initiateAuthResponse.ChallengeParameters.SECRET_BLOCK;
const session = initiateAuthResponse.Session;
```

4. Generate the `PASSWORD_CLAIM_SIGNATURE` and `TIMESTAMP` from user's password, userId, srpB and salt

```
   const hkdf = srp.getPasswordAuthenticationKey(
      userIdForSrp,
      pin, // This is the user's password
      srpB,
      salt,
    );
    const dateNow = getNowString();
    const signatureString = calculateSignature(
      hkdf,
      userPoolId,
      userIdForSrp,
      secretBlock,
      dateNow,
    );
```

5. RespondToAuthChallenge Command with relevant parameters

```
const respondToAuthParams: RespondToAuthChallengeCommandInput = {
      ClientId: this.clientId,
      ChallengeName: ChallengeNameType.PASSWORD_VERIFIER,
      ChallengeResponses: {
        PASSWORD_CLAIM_SIGNATURE: signatureString,
        PASSWORD_CLAIM_SECRET_BLOCK: secretBlock,
        TIMESTAMP: dateNow,
        USERNAME: userIdForSrp,
      },
      Session: session,
    };
    const respondToAuthCommand = new RespondToAuthChallengeCommand(
      respondToAuthParams,
    );
    const respondToAuthResponse = await this.provider.send(
      respondToAuthCommand,
    );
```

**Lambda Triggers**

I was referencing [this blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/extending-amazon-cognito-with-email-otp-for-2fa-using-amazon-ses/)

Create Auth Trigger

```
import { SNSClient, PublishCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-sns';
import { SESClient, SendEmailCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-ses';

const region = 'ap-southeast-1';
const snsClient = new SNSClient({ region });
const sesClient = new SESClient({ region });

export const handler = async (event) => {
  console.log('event: ');
  console.log(event);

  console.log('session');
  console.log(event.request.session);
  let otp;
  if (event.request.session.length === 2) {
    // Username password auth complete, generate OTP
    otp = generateOTP();
    await sendSMS(event.request.userAttributes.phone_number, otp);
    if (event.request.userAttributes.email) {
      await sendEmail(event.request.userAttributes.email, otp);
    }
  } else {
    // There's an existing session. Don't generate new digits but
    // re-use the code from the current session. This allows the user to
    // make a mistake when keying in the code and to then retry, rather
    // the needing to e-mail the user an all new code again.
    const previousChallenge = event.request.session.slice(-1)[0];
    otp = previousChallenge.challengeMetadata.match(/CODE-([A-Z]*-\d*)/)[1];
  }

  // This is sent back to the client app
  const otpPrefix = otp.split('-')[0];
  event.response.publicChallengeParameters = {
    otpPrefix,
  };

  // Add the secret login code to the private challenge parameters
  // so it can be verified by the "Verify Auth Challenge Response" trigger
  event.response.privateChallengeParameters = { secretLoginCode: otp };

  // Add the secret login code to the session so it is available
  // in a next invocation of the "Create Auth Challenge" trigger
  event.response.challengeMetadata = `CODE-${otp}`;

  return event;
};

function generateOTP() {
  const alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.toUpperCase();
  let letters = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    letters += alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)];
  }
  const numbers = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000)
    .toString()
    .padStart(6, '0');

  const output = `${letters}-${numbers}`;
  return output;
}

async function sendEmail(emailAddress, otp) {
  const params = {
    Destination: { ToAddresses: [emailAddress] },
    Message: {
      Body: {
        Html: {
          Charset: 'UTF-8',
          Data: `<html><body><p>Your OTP is:</p>
                           <h3>${otp}</h3></body></html>`,
        },
        Text: {
          Charset: 'UTF-8',
          Data: `Your secret login code: ${otp}`,
        },
      },
      Subject: {
        Charset: 'UTF-8',
        Data: 'Your One Time Password',
      },
    },
    Source: 'abc@abc.com',
  };
  const command = new SendEmailCommand(params);
  const response = await sesClient.send(command);
  return response;
}

async function sendSMS(phoneNumber, otp) {
  const otpMessage = 'Your OTP is: ' + otp;
  const params = {
    PhoneNumber: phoneNumber,
    Message: otpMessage,
  };

  try {
    const command = new PublishCommand(params);
    const response = await snsClient.send(command);
    console.log('Success. SMS Send Response: ', response);
    return response; // For unit tests.
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack);
  }
}
```

Define Auth Trigger

```
export const handler = async (event) => {
  console.log('event: ');
  console.log(event);
  if (
    event.request.session &&
    event.request.session.length === 1 &&
    event.request.session[0].challengeName === 'SRP_A' &&
    event.request.session[0].challengeResult === true
  ) {
    //SRP_A is the first challenge, this will be implemented by cognito. Set next challenge as PASSWORD_VERIFIER.
    event.response.issueTokens = false;
    event.response.failAuthentication = false;
    event.response.challengeName = 'PASSWORD_VERIFIER';
  } else if (
    event.request.session &&
    event.request.session.length === 2 &&
    event.request.session[1].challengeName === 'PASSWORD_VERIFIER' &&
    event.request.session[1].challengeResult === true
  ) {
    //If password verification is successful then set next challenge as CUSTOM_CHALLENGE.
    event.response.issueTokens = false;
    event.response.failAuthentication = false;
    event.response.challengeName = 'CUSTOM_CHALLENGE';
  } else if (
    event.request.session &&
    //first session is password verification, after that 3 tries for OTP
    event.request.session.length >= 5 &&
    event.request.session.slice(-1)[0].challengeResult === false
  ) {
    // The user provided a wrong answer 3 times; fail auth
    event.response.issueTokens = false;
    event.response.failAuthentication = true;
  } else if (
    event.request.session &&
    event.request.session.slice(-1)[0].challengeName === 'CUSTOM_CHALLENGE' &&
    event.request.session.slice(-1)[0].challengeResult === true
  ) {
    // The user provided the right answer; succeed auth
    event.response.issueTokens = true;
    event.response.failAuthentication = false;
  } else {
    // The user did not provide a correct answer yet; present challenge
    event.response.issueTokens = false;
    event.response.failAuthentication = false;
    event.response.challengeName = 'CUSTOM_CHALLENGE';
  }

  return event;
};
```

And lastly Verify Auth Trigger

```
export const handler = async (event) => {
  const expectedAnswer =
    event.request.privateChallengeParameters.secretLoginCode;
  if (event.request.challengeAnswer === expectedAnswer) {
    event.response.answerCorrect = true;
  } else {
    event.response.answerCorrect = false;
  }
  return event;
};
```